# Is there any way to migrate a full GTM setup from a normal site to a SPA?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am horrified of having to redo all the work did in Google's GTM in backbone events :) I see for angular there are some helpers that allow analytics and trackers to work in a SPA, but even that assumes new installations. And I don't even angular.

Is there a way to get GTM to refresh whenever history changes in Backbone? Like a hard reload of sorts :D

Comment: Maybe i could add more details just let me know :)

Comment: This isn't necessarily on-topic as there's no code to troubleshoot, but just to comment, GTM has history listeners that detect changes in the URL. This is particularly useful for SPAs. Here are a couple of useful resources: http://www.simoahava.com/analytics/google-tag-manager-history-listener/ and http://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/track-url-fragments-as-pageviews/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need some rework on your triggers, but you could probably get away with only that if you use [history change triggers](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6106961?hl=en):

> Triggers based on the History Change event will fire a tag when the URL fragment (hash) changes or when a site is using the HTML5 pushstate APIs.